# Finding the funtion through expression

Tags: calculus

There is the expression:
$$2f'(x)f(x)=2f(x)+2xf'(x)$$
and we are given that $f(0)=1$.
We are asked to prove that $f(x)=x+\sqrt{x^2+1}$.

I tried to rewrite the given expression as $$[f(x)^2]'=[2xf(x)]',$$but I was not able to reach the specific conclusion.
I would appreciate your guidance.
Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If $(f(x)^2)'=(2xf(x))'$ then we have that $f(x)^2=2xf(x)+C$, where $C$ is some constant. Since $f(0)=1$, $C=1$ by substitution. Hence we have that $f(x)^2=2xf(x)+1$, and so $f(x)^2-2xf(x)-1=0$. The quadratic formula tells us that $f(x)=\frac{2x\pm\sqrt{4x^2+4}}{2}$, which reduces to the required result. Substituting back in shows that it is indeed a valid solution. Note that we take the nonnegative square root because the solution $x-\sqrt{x^2+1}<0$ does not hold as $f(0)>0$.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out - I only calculated the discriminant....oops. But I've rectified this now

Comment: I saw (that's why I deleted my comment). Excellent answer!

Comment: Thank you very much, I really appreciate it:)

Comment: Thank you very much, be well and safe!